# How can I permanently set options in Slash'em?

Tags: nethack, slashem

In Slash'em (possibly the same in nethack) I can set options with `O`, but these opotion are set only for this game. How can I set options permanently?

Comment: What operative system?

Comment: Linux, but you answered it anyways for multiple systems. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Linux and OSX: Edit `~/.slashemrc`
- Windows: Edit the `slashem.cnf` file in your Nethack folder.

[This wiki page](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Options) is an excellent guide for Nethack configuration and should work without trouble on Slash'EM. More Slash'EM specific information can be found in [its man page.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man6/slashem.6.html)